Gilmore-Gomory TSP with Reversion
I am investigating a Gilmore-Gomory type of TSP with a special property. For your knowledge,
GG-Tsp's are a special type of TSP that are solvable in polynomial time. In the most simple case, a GG-TSP is given by a finite set of tuples $\{(a_i, b_i) \mid i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. As for any TSP, the goal is to find a permutation $\rho$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to arrange the tuples in a finite sequence $(a_{\rho(1)},b_{\rho(1)}), \ldots, (a_{\rho(n)},b_{\rho(n)})$ such that an objective function is minimized. The reason for polynomial complexity is the special type of objective function, it is an integrable function in the coordinates of the tuples. In the most simple case for example it is the sum of differences between consecutive numbers:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |a_{\rho(i+1 \pmod n)} - b_{\rho(i)}|$$
My question is now if this problem is still solvable in polynomial time if you are additionally allowed to reverse the tuples from $(a_i,b_i)$ to $(\tilde{a}_i := b_i, \tilde{b}_i := a_i)$ to achieve a better objective value. Thus you are not only confronted with finding a suitable permutation of the tuples, but also decide for each tuple to leave it as it is or swap it. The objective function is the same as before.
I would appreciate any tips or hints, i can not find anything in the literature as swapping does not make much sense for the usecase originally considered, which is basically flow shop scheduling with jobs that require a certain process temperature.
Thank you in advance.
